# looping inside folders and subfolders .net

Tags: vb.net, directory, subdirectory

```
    Dim txtbx As String = "E:\_net_programs\test"
    For Each d As String In Directory.GetDirectories(txtbx)
        'For Each di As file
        'Next
        'MessageBox.Show(d)
        'Dim folder As DirectoryInfo in directory
    Next
```

Please help me loop inside this folder "E:_net_programs\test" and open every sub folder

Comment: You should clarify what you want to do in the loop - get folder names? get files by folder?.  Looping is not an end unto itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's the code :

```
Dim txtbx As String = "E:\_net_programs\test"

For Each File In Directory.GetFiles(txtbx, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    MsgBox(File)
Next
```

If you don't want a loop of `String` but of `FileInfo` to be able to get their attributes (name, parent directory, extension, etc.), there's the code :

```
Dim txtbx As String = "E:\_net_programs\test"

For Each File As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(txtbx).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    MsgBox(File.FullName)
Next
```